# XSLT - get original attributes to the result tree

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have xml like this,

```
<doc>
    <section type="Main_Content">
        <p id="main">aa</p>
        <p id="main">bb</p>
        <p id="main">cc</p>
        <p id="para1">dd</p>
        <p id="main">ee</p>
        <p id="main">ff</p>
        <p id="para2">hh</p>
        <p id="main">ii</p>
        <p id="main">jj</p>
        <p id="para1">xx</p>
        <p id="main">yy</p>

    </section>
    <section type="Main_Chapter">
        <p id="main">ii</p>
        <p id="main">jj</p>
        <p id="para1">xx</p>
        <p id="main">yy</p>
        <p id="main">zz</p>    
    </section>
</doc>
```

my task is group the above content based on id="para1" and id='para2' attributes and add a section to each group. My desired output is

```
<doc>
    <section type="Main_Content">
        <p id="main">aa</p>
        <p id="main">bb</p>
        <p id="main">cc</p>
    </section>
    <section type="First para">
        <p id="para1">dd</p>
        <p id="main">ee</p>
        <p id="main">ff</p>
    </section>
    <section type="Second para">
        <p id="para2">hh</p>
        <p id="main">ii</p>
        <p id="main">jj</p>
    </section>
    <section type="First para">
        <p id="para1">xx</p>
        <p id="main">yy</p>
    </section>
    <section type="Main_Chapter">
        <p id="main">ii</p>
        <p id="main">jj</p>
    </section>
    <section type="First para">
        <p id="para1">xx</p>
        <p id="main">yy</p>
        <p id="main">zz</p>
    </section>
</doc>
```

The XSL code to this task is,

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="section">
        <xsl:for-each-group select="p" group-starting-with="p[starts-with(@id, 'para')]">
            <section type="{@type}">
                <xsl:if test="current-group()[1][@id='para1']">
                    <xsl:attribute name="type" select="'First para'"/>
                </xsl:if>
                <xsl:if test="current-group()[1][@id='para2']">
                    <xsl:attribute name="type" select="'Second para'"/>
                </xsl:if>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
            </section>      
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:template>
```

The result that getting from above xsl is,

```
<doc>
    <section type="">
        <p id="main">aa</p>
        <p id="main">bb</p>
        <p id="main">cc</p>
    </section>
    <section type="First para">
        <p id="para1">dd</p>
        <p id="main">ee</p>
        <p id="main">ff</p>
    </section>
    <section type="Second para">
        <p id="para2">hh</p>
        <p id="main">ii</p>
        <p id="main">jj</p>
    </section>
    <section type="First para">
        <p id="para1">xx</p>
        <p id="main">yy</p>
    </section>
    <section type="">
        <p id="main">ii</p>
        <p id="main">jj</p>
    </section>
    <section type="First para">
        <p id="para1">xx</p>
        <p id="main">yy</p>
        <p id="main">zz</p>
    </section>
</doc>
```

SO, As it seems in the result everting is correct except the original `type` attributes is not copied to the `<section>` node. How can modified the xsl to get original `type` attribute values to `<section>` nodes ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is in this part of the provided code:

```
<xsl:template match="section">
    <xsl:for-each-group select="p" group-starting-with="p[starts-with(@id, 'para')]">
        <section type="{@type}">
```

Do notice that the context (current) item is a `p` element, and none of these in the provided source XML document have a `type` attribute.

**Here you want the `type` attribute of the parent of the `p` element**.

**Solution**:

Replace:

```
        <section type="{@type}">
```

with:

```
        <section type="{../@type}">
```

**Now the whole transformation becomes**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="section">
   <xsl:for-each-group select="p"  group-starting-with="p[starts-with(@id, 'para')]">
      <section type="{../@type}">
        <xsl:if test="current-group()[1][@id='para1']">
           <xsl:attribute name="type" select="'First para'"/>
         </xsl:if>
         <xsl:if test="current-group()[1][@id='para2']">
            <xsl:attribute name="type" select="'Second para'"/>
          </xsl:if>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
      </section>      
   </xsl:for-each-group>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**and when applied on the provided source XML document**:

```
<doc>
    <section type="Main_Content">
        <p id="main">aa</p>
        <p id="main">bb</p>
        <p id="main">cc</p>
        <p id="para1">dd</p>
        <p id="main">ee</p>
        <p id="main">ff</p>
        <p id="para2">hh</p>
        <p id="main">ii</p>
        <p id="main">jj</p>
        <p id="para1">xx</p>
        <p id="main">yy</p>
    </section>
    <section type="Main_Chapter">
        <p id="main">ii</p>
        <p id="main">jj</p>
        <p id="para1">xx</p>
        <p id="main">yy</p>
        <p id="main">zz</p>
    </section>
</doc>
```

**The wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
<doc>
   <section type="Main_Content">
      <p id="main">aa</p>
      <p id="main">bb</p>
      <p id="main">cc</p>
   </section>
   <section type="First para">
      <p id="para1">dd</p>
      <p id="main">ee</p>
      <p id="main">ff</p>
   </section>
   <section type="Second para">
      <p id="para2">hh</p>
      <p id="main">ii</p>
      <p id="main">jj</p>
   </section>
   <section type="First para">
      <p id="para1">xx</p>
      <p id="main">yy</p>
   </section>
      <section type="Main_Chapter">
      <p id="main">ii</p>
      <p id="main">jj</p>
   </section>
   <section type="First para">
      <p id="para1">xx</p>
      <p id="main">yy</p>
      <p id="main">zz</p>
   </section>
</doc>
```